# How can I create a wind visual effect like Ori?

Tags: shaders, graphics-programming, graphic-effects, visualization

I'm working on a mobile game in Cocos2D. The game mechanic is very similar to Ori and the Blind Forest's parachute (Kuro's feather) mechanic. I want to be able to render a visual effect for wind similar to Ori's (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6y0rUnY4TU)) to make parachuting feel better, but I'm a bit at a loss on how to do it.

Do I make a custom shader that draws everything from scratch? Do I start with a wind texture and apply some transformations to it?

I think adding particles that blow around in the wind is pretty simple but the ribbony wind field look in addition to particles would feel much better.

In case the video dies (but an image doesn't do the effect justice, it's very dynamic):
[image: Wind Escape screenshot]

Comment: The bulk of this effect looks like a tiling [ridge noise texture](https://www.google.ca/search?q=perlin+ridge+noise&source=lnms&tbm=isch), stretched vertically and scrolling upward.